# two divs appearing on the same line

Tags: html, css

In the html below, there's two nested divs with a class "ejector". In side one of the ejector class divs is the word "female" and in the other "male." I want those words to appear not against the colored backgrounds (pink and green respectively) but rather against the white after the bars end. The word "females" should appear on the white background just after the green bar ends (but the number 25 stays on the green bar). In order to achieve that I gave the ejector class a `float:right` and a value of `-15` for a margin-right, hoping that would push it outside the boundary of the nested div (but keep it on the same line) so the words appear on the white backgorund. It didn't work. You can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/kpPbE/10/

Can you tell me how to achieve what I'm trying to achieve

Note, I also tried to remove the nested div and just position it next to the div with the desired background color with a `float:left` but the text appeared below the desired colored background http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/kpPbE/12/

```
<div class="chart" style="width:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
    <h4 style="width:600px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">Visitors to StackOverflow</h4>

    <div class="pink" style="width: 50px;">25 <div class="ejector">females</div></div>
    <div class="green" style="width: 30px;">15 <div class="ejector">males</div></div>

</div>
```

css

```
chart div {

        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: #000;
        width: 600px;
      }
      .green {
        font: 15px sans-serif;
        background-color: green;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
        height: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
      }
      .pink  {
        font: 15px sans-serif;
        background-color: #f5c5f2;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
        height: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
      }

     .ejector{
    float:right;
    margin-right: -15px;

  }
```

Comment: Probs a typo, but you forgot a `.` before `chart` (also in 2 fiddles). *A picture is worth a thousand words* (would be easier to visualize the desired result). From what I understood you want `number(in color bg) + word(in white bg)` for both lines, with a varying width, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `absolute` or `relative` positioning, though using the latter will be a little more complicated. So for simplicity's sake, let's use the former.

Set the container divs (`.green` and `.pink`)'s CSS to `position: relative;` so it will be used as root for the absolutely positioned elements. The new CSS for your `.ejector` class will be as follows:

```
div.ejector{
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    top: 0; /* makes sure the word is at same height as the number */
    left: 100%; /* sets the word 100% of whatever the width from its parent */
    margin-left: 10px; /* any value to space the words from the colored bars */
}
```

There's one issue with the absolute positioning: if you want to put flow elements after your `div`'s, they will overlap that content. So we can simply put a `margin-right` on the `.green` and `.pink divs` that accounts for that extra space, eg. the size of each ejector div +10px (to put some spacing), here that would be 57px & 71px.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kpPbE/13/

Comment: works on jsfiddle, but not on my local site. The words "females" and "males" are positioned in the very top left of the website. know why?

Comment: Probably because you didn't set the `.green` and `.pink` divs `position: relative;`. I can't see no other cause than that.

Comment: but you didn't set those divs to `position: relative;` either. As with your fiddle, I set `.chart div`like this ` position: relative;`.

Comment: `.chart div` is the same as `.green` & `.pink`, so that means somewhere  in your CSS a rule may have overwritten it. You can check that in your console. You can set a more speficic selector, eg. `div.chart div.green, div.chart div.pink` or if it still doesn't work, set `position: relative !important;`. I am certain the issue you described is related to the relative property not being set, that's why it takes the document as root.

Comment: how did you calculate the size of each ejector div to come up with the numbers 57px (47 + 10 for spacing) and 71px (61 +10 for spacing)? there's no side property set on them? I need to know this when I set other margin-rights in my actual application

Comment: Open browser console, hover over element, displays the computed size :) You could also detect it with JS & set it dynamically with `.clientWidth`

Answer (score 1):

try this if it is what you need

```
<div class="chart" style="width:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
<h4 style="width:600px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">Visitors to StackOverflow</h4>

<span class="pink" style="width: 50px;">25 </span ><span>females</span><br>
<span class="green" style="width: 30px;">15 </span><span>males</span>
```

there is no need for the ejector class , issues in ur code are:

```
<div class="pink" style="width: 50px;">25 <div class="ejector">females</div></div>
```

you are setting the div of females inside the div of pink background which means the pink background will apply on it .
second issue is that  element is a block level element which means the div of class pink will take the whole line and the next element will be on a new line , instead use span which is inline element .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a couple of issues.

1. Changing the `<div>` for the colors to `<span>` would work better
2. Remove the ejector `<div>` completely.
3. add `display: inline-block` to the css for `.pink` and `.green`. This will allow you to give the `<span>` a width.

It's not working because you're containing the ejector `<div>` within the defined width of the pink/green `<div>`.

Additionally, depending on your needs, you can then contain each of those lines within a `<div>,` or a `<p>`.

Here's a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5hwVH/5/

And, here's the updated html:

```
<div class="chart" style="width:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
    <h4 style="width:600px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">Visitors to StackOverflow</h4>

    <div>
        <span class="pink" style="width: 50px;">25</span> females
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="green" style="width: 30px;">15</span> males
    </div>

</div>
```

And, the CSS

```
.chart div {

        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: #000;
        width: 600px;
      }
      .green, .pink {
        font: 15px sans-serif;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
        height: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .green {
        background-color: green;
      }
      .pink {
        background-color: #f5c5f2;
      }

      }
```

As you can see, I also combined much of `.pink` and `.green`. It's good practice to combine your CSS where possible, and where it makes sense. It cuts down on maintenance in the future.

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work, the Result section is empty except for the heading "visitors to stack overflow"

Comment: I'll second that, good answer. The only resulting difference from my fiddle is that the content here is aligned right.